# How to set the r_bar part of tqdm

Tags: python-3.x, tqdm

I use tqdm to print a progress bar for a long running optimization process with hyperopt.
The process calls a function say 500 times and each call will take around 10 to 20 minutes, so I started to make the progress display a bit more fine granular and added some `tqdm.update`-statements in the loop, advancing the progress bar fraction-wise to avoid having two nested progress bars while still beeing able to immediately see how many function calls have been performed so far.

Now the ugly result looks like this:

```
 15%|███▌                    | 73.69999999999993/500 [7:40:31<102:54:08, 868.98s/it, evaluating fold 2 of  2 folds...]Iteration 1, loss = 2.50358388
```

You can see above, it is the 73th call of the function and this 73th function call is about 70% finished. In fact I just estimated the number of substeps `m` in the function (which might vary from call to call) and used the fraction `1/m` to update the progress bar. Then after the function call I just synchronize the progress bar back to a full integer to avoid adding rounding errors.

Of course accuracy is not an issue at all here. But I would like to display 73.70 rather than 73.69999999999993.
I already tried to round my update value to two decimal places, which  doesn't fix the problem, because of precision issues in float, if a number is not exactly representable by a float, then it gets ugly-long again.
According to the [documentation of tqdm](https://tqdm.github.io/docs/tqdm/) this part is hidden in the in the part `r_bar` of the whole format string, but I couldn't find a way to set it. Can you help me with this?

According to the docs `r_bar` defaults to:

```
r_bar='| {n_fmt}/{total_fmt} [{elapsed}<{remaining}, '
```

Here is my code:

```
with tqdm(iterable=None, initial=num_trials, maxinterval=maxinterval, total=max_evals, ascii=False, disable=show_progressbar is False) as progress_bar:
    def fn_to_minimize(*args, **kwargs):
        return fn(*args, **kwargs, _progress_bar=progress_bar)

    for num_trials in range(num_trials, max_evals):
        progress_bar.n=float(num_trials)
        progress_bar.refresh()
        best = fmin(**kwargs, fn=fn_to_minimize, trials=trials, max_evals=num_trials+1)

# do some other stuff here
```

In the called function (one of the entries in `kwargs` btw) I update the progress bar just like this:

```
_progress_bar.update(round(update_value, 2))
```

Comment: You can probably check out the part in the documentation where it says `format_meter`, you can pass in parameters to customise it. `tqdm.format_meter(n, total, elapsed, ncols=None, prefix='', ascii=False, unit='it', unit_scale=False, rate=None, bar_format=None, postfix=None, unit_divisor=1000, **extra_kwargs)` under the bar_format

Comment: Thank's for your comment. Can I relly just set `bar_format` to {l_bar}{bar}{r_bar}' and replace `{r_bar}` directly with something like `'| {n_fmt:.2f}/{total_fmt} [{elapsed}<{remaining}, ' '{rate_fmt}{postfix}]'`? It looks like there is a typo in the documentation (because of the two ' in the string)

Comment: Ok, I see, this doesn't just build the format string but builts a progress bar display. So I would have to do it everywhere I use the progress bar.

Comment: I am on my phone now, but i have briefly read through the code and apparently the parameters you pass in will be taken care of by the code

Comment: Ok, I'll check that. Thank you.

Comment: I've actually looked around in github and the source code, however I am unable to find the right answer. Apparent `r_bar` searches for the key "n_fmt" . You cannot do `{n_fmt:.2f}` because it will literally edit the number to look like for e.g: `12345:.2f`. The only way around it is to edit the source of it under the `r_bar = '| {0}/{1} [{2}<{3}, {4}{5}]'.format(
            n_fmt, total_fmt, elapsed_str, remaining_str, rate_fmt, postfix)` where you can possibly replace like `{0:.2f}`.

Comment: the parameter `l_bar` is editable because in the source code, its "overridable", for example you can do `bar_format = "{desc}: {percentage:.10f}%|{bar}| {n_fmt}/{total_fmt} [{elapsed}<{remaining}")` and it will show the percentage up till 10 decimal places.

Comment: Hi @Axois thank you for your analysis. Though subclassing would be an option, I'd like to avoid it, if possible, because I might add some dependencies to the version of tqm. In the meantime I found out, that if I supply the fully unfolded bar format (I mean with `r_bar` replaced by it's definition and change `{n_fmt}` to `{n:.2f}` (`n_fmt` is already a string) it displays what I want.

Comment: I just tried that and it works! Good to know. Do you mind if I type out an answer so that people can at least have a solution for future reference?

Comment: If there was a possibility to get the current automatically prebuilt format string from the `tqm` object, I could just extract it and string-replace `{n_fmt}` by `{n:.2f}`, so the code would be pretty safe. But unfortunately there does not seem to be a method to get the current pattern. I mean if the default pattern is used. I seems that the format is only stored in the `format_dict` if it was previously set over the interface. It seens ut does not contain the default pattern.

Comment: Good idea. I'll accept it then.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For rounding issues in `tqdm`, you can directly edit the formatting in the `r_bar` as one of the parameters in the `bar_format`. For example:

```
from tqdm import trange
for i in trange(int(7e7), bar_format = "{desc}: {percentage:.3f}%|{bar}| {n_fmt}/{total_fmt} [{elapsed}<{remaining}"):
    pass
```

shows: [image]

For 2 decimal places, you can simply edit the `{n_fmt}` to be `{n:.2f}` . You can also edit other parameters such as `{desc}` or add in additional decimal places to the `percentage`.

```
from tqdm import trange
for i in trange(int(7e7), bar_format = "{desc}: {percentage:.10f}%|{bar}| {n:.2f}/{total_fmt} [{elapsed}<{remaining}"):
    pass
```

shows:
[image]

Upon looking through the source code of `tqdm`, `n_fmt` is actually pointing to `str(n)`, hence passing in the formatted version of `n` can bypass its intrinsic formatting.

```
if unit_scale:
            n_fmt = format_sizeof(n, divisor=unit_divisor)
            total_fmt = format_sizeof(total, divisor=unit_divisor) \
                if total is not None else '?'
        else:
            n_fmt = str(n)
            total_fmt = str(total) if total is not None else '?'

        try:
            postfix = ', ' + postfix if postfix else ''
        except TypeError:
            pass
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your analysis and the time you spent on this.

Comment: @jottbe My pleasure :), I have learnt something from this too!

Comment: Btw. because of this I learnt to know class `Decimal` :-) though this knowledge didn't help me on this (would have been an ugly solution and tqdm doesn't seem to like decimals) maybe I can use it somewhere else.